# How to delete a specific attachment using TFS api 2010, 2012?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

How to delete a attachment in attachments collection using TFS api 2010, 2012.
I only know wi.Attachments.Clear(); to delete all attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way? I tried and succeeded.

```
//wi is a WorkItem  
wi.Open();  
for (int i = wi.Attachments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)  
{  
    if (wi.Attachments[i].Name == "Attach1.txt")  
    wi.Attachments.RemoveAt(i);  
}  
wi.Save();
wi.Close();
```

Comment: Good solution, You have just saved my life